# Can't launch Sinatra app on Apache

Tags: ruby, apache, deployment, sinatra

So I have a sinatra app that runs fine on my local machine. The directory structure is:

```
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── Rakefile
├── app
│   ├── controllers
│   │   └── bike_share_app.rb
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── city.rb
│   │   ├── condition.rb
│   │   ├── csv_loader.rb
│   │   ├── station.rb
│   │   └── trip.rb
│   └── views
│       ├── cities
│       │   ├── city.erb
│       │   ├── index.erb
│       │   └── new.erb
│       ├── conditions
│       │   ├── edit.erb
│       │   ├── index.erb
│       │   ├── new.erb
│       │   ├── show.erb
│       │   └── weather_dashboard.erb
│       ├── home.erb
│       ├── stations
│       │   ├── edit.erb
│       │   ├── index.erb
│       │   ├── new.erb
│       │   ├── show.erb
│       │   └── station_dashboard.erb
│       └── trips
│           ├── edit.erb
│           ├── index.erb
│           ├── new.erb
│           ├── show.erb
│           └── trip_dashboard.erb
├── config
│   ├── database.rb
│   ├── database.yml
│   └── environment.rb
├── config.ru
├── db
│   ├── csv
│   │   ├── station.csv
│   │   ├── status.csv
│   │   ├── trip.csv
│   │   └── weather.csv
│   ├── migrate
│   │   ├── 20170506165638_create_stations.rb
│   │   ├── 20170506225107_fix_date_type.rb
│   │   ├── 20170507184336_create_cities.rb
│   │   ├── 20170507184847_change_city_column_in_stations.rb
│   │   ├── 20170508201547_create_trips.rb
│   │   ├── 20170509023655_update_trip_zip_type.rb
│   │   ├── 20170509220039_create_conditions.rb
│   │   ├── 20170509222446_fix_date_column_in_conditions.rb
│   │   ├── 20170510175115_change_date_string_to_date_object.rb
│   │   ├── 20170511050518_change_date_string_to_date_object_in_conditions.rb
│   │   └── 20170511055446_add_index_to_trip_start_date.rb
│   ├── schema.rb
│   └── seeds.rb
├── public
│   ├── assets
│   │   └── bicycle.svg
│   ├── css
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── js
│   └── stylesheets
└── spec
    ├── controllers
    ├── features
    │   ├── condition_crud_spec.rb
    │   ├── station_crud_spec.rb
    │   └── trip_crud_spec.rb
    ├── fixtures
    │   └── trip_fixture.csv
    ├── models
    │   ├── city_spec.rb
    │   ├── csv_loader_spec.rb
    │   ├── station_spec.rb
    │   └── trip_spec.rb
    └── spec_helper.rb
```

The structure I've made on my debian server running apache and passenger is the following (Note: I read in the docs that I need a public and temp folder. So I moved all my css and views to public, and put the rest of my app in the root directory)

```
├── app
│   ├── controllers
│   │   └── bike_share_app.rb
│   └── models
│       ├── city.rb
│       ├── condition.rb
│       ├── csv_loader.rb
│       ├── station.rb
│       └── trip.rb
├── config
│   ├── database.rb
│   ├── database.yml
│   └── environment.rb
├── config.ru
├── db
│   ├── csv
│   │   ├── station.csv
│   │   ├── status.csv
│   │   ├── trip.csv
│   │   └── weather.csv
│   ├── migrate
│   │   ├── 20170506165638_create_stations.rb
│   │   ├── 20170506225107_fix_date_type.rb
│   │   ├── 20170507184336_create_cities.rb
│   │   ├── 20170507184847_change_city_column_in_stations.rb
│   │   ├── 20170508201547_create_trips.rb
│   │   ├── 20170509023655_update_trip_zip_type.rb
│   │   ├── 20170509220039_create_conditions.rb
│   │   ├── 20170509222446_fix_date_column_in_conditions.rb
│   │   ├── 20170510175115_change_date_string_to_date_object.rb
│   │   ├── 20170511050518_change_date_string_to_date_object_in_conditions.rb
│   │   └── 20170511055446_add_index_to_trip_start_date.rb
│   ├── schema.rb
│   └── seeds.rb
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── logs
│   ├── access.log
│   └── error.log
├── public
│   ├── assets
│   │   └── bicycle.svg
│   ├── css
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── js
│   ├── stylesheets
│   └── views
│       ├── cities
│       │   ├── city.erb
│       │   ├── index.erb
│       │   └── new.erb
│       ├── conditions
│       │   ├── edit.erb
│       │   ├── index.erb
│       │   ├── new.erb
│       │   ├── show.erb
│       │   └── weather_dashboard.erb
│       ├── edit.erb
│       ├── home.erb
│       ├── index.erb
│       ├── new.erb
│       ├── station_dashboard.erb
│       ├── station.erb
│       ├── stations
│       │   ├── edit.erb
│       │   ├── index.erb
│       │   ├── new.erb
│       │   ├── show.erb
│       │   └── station_dashboard.erb
│       └── trips
│           ├── edit.erb
│           ├── index.erb
│           ├── new.erb
│           ├── show.erb
│           └── trip_dashboard.erb
├── Rakefile
├── spec
│   ├── controllers
│   ├── features
│   │   ├── condition_crud_spec.rb
│   │   ├── station_crud_spec.rb
│   │   └── trip_crud_spec.rb
│   ├── fixtures
│   │   └── trip_fixture.csv
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── city_spec.rb
│   │   ├── csv_loader_spec.rb
│   │   ├── station_spec.rb
│   │   └── trip_spec.rb
│   └── spec_helper.rb
└── tmp
    └── restart.txt
```

Navigating to my host in my browser gives me the "App Failed to Start" passenger error. Here are the access logs:

`- - [14/May/2017:10:00:47 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 5133 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
 - - [14/May/2017:10:00:48 -0500] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 5133 "http://IP/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5$
 - - [14/May/2017:10:00:51 -0500] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 5133 "http://IP/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5$
 - - [14/May/2017:10:02:18 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 5133 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
IP - - [14/May/2017:10:02:19 -0500] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 5133 "http://IP/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5$
 - - [14/May/2017:10:02:57 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 5133 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,  - - [14/May/2017:10:02:57 -0500] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 5133 "http://IP/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5$
 - - [14/May/2017:10:04:05 -0500] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 5133 "http://IP/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5$`

I'm assuming my directory structure is buggered. Any advice? P.S. sorry for the long walls of directory tree text

EDIT: Here is my conf:

```
VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName localhost
     DocumentRoot /var/www/figgus/public
     PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby2.1
     ServerAlias figgus
     ErrorLog /var/www/figgus/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/figgus/logs/access.log combined

    # Relax Apache security settings
    <Directory /var/www/figgus/public>
      Allow from all
      Options -MultiViews
      # Uncomment this if you're on Apache > 2.4:
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Also, how should I be starting this? I've been stopping/starting apache, running rackup, even shotgun, but none of the ports work nor does connecting to just the host (default port 80)

Comment: Instead of access_log, you should look into error log file of Apache